# Routes having conflict in URL rewriting or configuring route in ASP.NET Web API

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api-routing

I am developing an ASP.Net MVC application. In my project I am providing REST API for mobile devices. But I am having a problem with configuring route for URLs of my rest API in Web Api. I am using Web Api 2 and MVC 5. My problem is routes having conflict. Request cannot choose the correct route even I configured it clearly.

I have AccountController like this.

```
[RoutePrefix("v1")]
public class AccountController : ApiController
{
    public UserManager<ApplicationUser> UserManager { get; private set; }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Register(RegisterBM model)
    {

    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult Login(LoginBM model)
    {

    }
}
```

I configured routes in WebApiConfig like this

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "",
    routeTemplate: "api/v1/account/register",
    defaults: new { controller = "Account", action = "Register" ,model = RouteParameter.Optional }
);

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "",
    routeTemplate: "api/v1/account/login",
    defaults: new { controller = "Account", action = "Login", model = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

These are my model classes

```
public class LoginBM
{
    [Required]
    [EmailAddress]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Password { get; set; }
}

public class RegisterBM
{
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [EmailAddress]
    [MaxLength(70)]
    [UniqueAccountEmail(ErrorMessage = "Email is alreay taken")]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
    public string Password { get; set; }
    [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
}
```

This is error I get when I make request to http://localhost:50489/api/account/login

[image]

What is wrong with my route configuration? How can I fix that?

Comment: Is this your only controller called AccountController (having the Register and Login methods)? If not, you might need to distinguish between them somehow - for example naming them differently (e.g. using ApiController suffix for your WebAPI controllers) or introducing them in different scopes (a scope for MVC and another for WebAPI).

Comment: Its been a while since I worked with web API. But, there are two types of routing. convention based vs attribute routing. I believe, in your scenario, you will have to use attribute routing. Try placing `Route["/register"]` and `Route["/login"]` on top of relevant methods and it should work.

Comment: I added  [Route("login")] and  [Route("register")]. But it saying not action found that matches the request. @MuhammadAdeelZahid

Comment: When there is only register method. It workis. But when I added Login action, it starts giving me that error. @MattStuvysant

Comment: have u tried adding `/` before login and register. The error comes because both your routes map to `/v1` on `POST` request according to conventional routing

Comment: Cannot add "/" prefix to it. It will throw error.

Comment: Not it saying action that matches request in Account Controller does not exist. It mapped to Account. But cannot map to action.

Comment: I found the error. Actually there is an mvc controller named AccountController. But I did not think that is error cause when there was only register action in AccountController that extends ApiController, it is working. But when I added Login action, it stopped working. That is why I did not think AccountController that extends normal Controller is making error. I changed my ApiController name to AccountsController and now it is working. Thanks to all of you for helpinh me. That is my mistake.

Comment: The URL you are testing `http://localhost:50489/api/account/login` does not match the `routeTemplate` of the route you have provided `api/v1/account/login`, namely you are missing `v1` from the URL. Your test is apparently reaching another route, which is causing this exception.

Comment: So it does not matter if I have same api controller with MVC Normal Controller? @NightOwl888

Comment: Since Web API and MVC are separate frameworks, each has their own controllers. URLs must be unique for the application, but route values are not shared between them. So you can use the same set of route values in both frameworks (same names for controllers and actions) provided you give each framework unique URLs. Generally, this is done by prefixing the Web Api URL with `/api` (which you have already done). But if you put a version in the `routeTemplate`, you must also use it in the actual URL or you will not reach the controller action.

Comment: Thanks so much. You help me all the time. @NightOwl888

Comment: @NightOwl: would you be able to pop down a summary answer for this question? It'd be nice to get an answer below that can be accepted.

Comment: I have finally answered! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL you are testing `http://localhost:50489/api/account/login` does not match the `routeTemplate` of the route you have provided `api/v1/account/login`, namely you are missing `v1` from the URL. Your test is apparently reaching another route, which is causing this exception.

Since Web API and MVC are separate frameworks, each has their own controllers. URLs must be unique for the application, but route values are not shared between them. So you can use the same set of route values in both frameworks (same names for controllers and actions) provided you use unique URLs across them both. Generally, this is done by prefixing the Web Api URL with `/api` (which you have already done). But if you put a version in the `routeTemplate`, you must also use it in the actual URL or you will not reach the controller action.